# Why does sphere get distorted when is drawn by Opengl and doing a perspective projection?

Tags: qt, opengl

[image]

while other objects are not distorted or stretched, after a perspective projection my sphere is getting distorted.

it is ok with ortho projection but it gets stretched when projecting using QMatrix4x4::perspective. I hoped it should work but it goes very tricky here.
The code for drawing sphere is comming below:

```
    #include "ballshader.h"

#include <iostream>

void BallShader::initialize(float r)
{
  m_program.addCacheableShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "vsrc.vsh");
   m_program.addCacheableShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "fsrc.fsh");
if (m_program.link())
{
    std::cout << "link ok"<<std::endl;
}
//else
{
    std::cout << "link nok" << std::endl;
    
}

m_r = r;

/// p3    p2
///
/// p0    p1
///
int angleSpan = 10; //radian = angle * PI / 180
for (int vAngle = -90; vAngle <90; vAngle = vAngle + angleSpan) { //Generate spherical vertices
    for (int hAngle = 0; hAngle <= 360; hAngle = hAngle + angleSpan) {
        float x0 = r * ::cosf(vAngle * PI / 180.0) * ::cosf(hAngle * PI / 180.0);
        float y0 = r * ::cosf(vAngle * PI / 180.0) * ::sinf(hAngle * PI / 180.0);
        float z0 = r * ::sinf(vAngle * PI / 180.0);

        float x1 = r * ::cosf(vAngle * PI / 180.0) * ::cosf((hAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0);
        float y1 = r * ::cosf(vAngle * PI / 180.0) * ::sinf((hAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0);
        float z1 = r * ::sinf(vAngle * PI / 180.0);

        float x2 = r * ::cosf((vAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0) * ::cosf((hAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0);
        float y2 = r * ::cosf((vAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0) * ::sinf((hAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0);
        float z2 = r * ::sinf((vAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0);

        float x3 = r * ::cosf((vAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0) * ::cosf(hAngle * PI / 180.0);
        float y3 = r * ::cosf((vAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0) * ::sinf(hAngle * PI / 180.0);
        float z3 = r * ::sinf((vAngle + angleSpan) * PI / 180.0);

        // p1 -> p3 -> p0
        // p1 -> p2 -> p3

        m_points
            << x1 << y1 << z1
            << x3 << y3 << z3
            << x0 << y0 << z0
            << x1 << y1 << z1
            << x2 << y2 << z2
            << x3 << y3 << z3;

            /*//normals
            << x1 / r << y1 / r << z1 / r
            << x3 / r << y3 / r << z3 / r
            << x0 / r << y0 / r << z0 / r
            << x1 / r << y1 / r << z1 / r
            << x2 / r << y2 / r << z2 / r
            << x3 / r << y3 / r << z3 / r;*/

    }
}
m_vbo.create();
m_vbo.bind();
m_vbo.allocate(m_points.constData(), m_points.count() * sizeof GLfloat);
m_vbo.release();
}

void BallShader::render(QOpenGLFunctions *f, QMatrix4x4 & projM, QMatrix4x4 & camera, QMatrix4x4 & model, const QVector3D &eye)
{

f->glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0f);
f->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
f->glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
f->glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
m_program.bind();
m_vbo.bind();
m_program.setUniformValue("uPMatrix", projM);
m_program.setUniformValue("camMatrix", camera);
m_program.setUniformValue("uMMatrix", model);
m_program.setUniformValue("uR", m_r);
m_program.setUniformValue("objectColor", 1, 0.3f, 0.3f);
m_program.setUniformValue("lightColor", 1, 1, 1);
m_program.setUniformValue("viewPos", eye);
m_program.setUniformValue("lightPos", eye);

m_program.enableAttributeArray(0);
m_program.setAttributeBuffer(0, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT));

f->glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_points.count() / 3);

m_program.disableAttributeArray(0);
m_vbo.release();
m_program.release();
f->glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
f->glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

Comment: This is the perspective distortion. The distortion increases at the edges of the view. Draw the sphere in the center of the view and see the difference.

Comment: yes. it looks ok when it is drawn on the center. but I want to circulate the sphere around the edges.

Comment: What is the question? There is nothing wrong in your screenshot. Use a smaller field of view angle and increase the distance between the camera and the objects to make the effect less noticeable. Use orthographic projection if you don't want any perspective distortion. You are actually seeing what is being seen through a [Wide-angle lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-angle_lens).

Comment: I want my spheres to walk around the edges of near plane of the frustum. I also need to see the depth so I need the perspective projection.

Comment: I can just repeat the last comment: Use a smaller field of view angle and increase the distance between the camera and the objects to make the effect less noticeable.

Comment: I use a 45.0 fov degree for my perspective projection so the distance of camera to the near plane equals the height of the near plane but It seems that the near plane height is bigger than I expected and it is a contradiction to the geometry. isn't it?

Comment: "but It seems that the near plane height is bigger than I expected and it is a contradiction to the geometry. isn't it?" The information given in the question is not sufficient to com e to any conclusion. But the screenshot looks a bit more wide-angle than what I would expect from a 45 degree fov, and my first hunch would be that you're use the 45 as radians.

Comment: No. the input of perspective method of QMatrix4*4 is degree and I passed 45.0 degree